# Extra zero in final out put where does it come from?

Tags: c#, loops, logic

I wrote this code to order any set of numbers from biggest to smallest, but for whatever reason, the output always has a zero at the end. My question is, where did it come from? (new to coding)

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter set of numbers");
int input = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

int counter= 1;
int temp1;
int temp2;
int[] array = new int[input+1];

for (int i = 0; i <=input-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter entry number " + counter);
    int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    array[i] = number;
        counter++;
}
for (int x = 0; x <= input; x++)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <=input; i++)
    {
        if (array[i - 1] <= array[i])
        {
            temp1 = array[i - 1];
            temp2 = array[i];
            array[i - 1] = temp2;
            array[i] = temp1;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
for (int i = 0; i<=input; i++)
{
    Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please take more time to format your code in future - and what does this have to do with xcode?

Answer (score 4):

You're inconsistent between whether you're trying to handle `input + 1` or `input` elements. For example:

```
int[] array = new int[input+1];

for (int i = 0; i <=input-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter entry number " + counter);
    int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    array[i] = number;
    counter++;
}
```

You're creating an array with `input + 1` elements, but only populating `input` of them.

In general, it's *much* more common to use exclusive upper boundaries for loops. For example:

```
int[] array = new int[input];

for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
    // No need for the counter variable at all
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter entry number " + (i + 1));
    int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    array[i] = number;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, by populating."[input+1]" is to keep the program from crashing because of an out of range error and input -1 is a way to keep the loop from going one over what the user had intended. @Jon Skeet

Comment: @JimRoberts: By "populating" I mean that you're only asking for `input` values... ""[input+1]" is to keep the program from crashing because of an out of range error" That's not the right way to fix a bug. You should work out *why* you were getting an out of range error. Note that in the bottom part of you're code, you're printing out all `input + 1` values, so one of those is bound to be 0.

Comment: I tried to int[] array = new int[input] but it crashes when it runs through the if statement because array = new int[input] starts at 0. I don't see any other way around it. The bottom part of the code it prints out integer at any given interval of the array. input+1 values@Jon Skeets

Comment: "I don't see any other way around it." Well you need to look closer then. The problem isn't because the array starts at 0 - the problem is at the *top* end, because you're using inclusive upper bounds (e.g. `for (int i = 1; i <=input; i++)`). You should step through this in the debugger, line by line, working out *exactly* what's happening at each point. Logically, you only want `input` elements, right? (That's how many you're prompting the user for.) So you should be able to get it to work with that many elements.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention with this code. Console.WriteLine("Please enter entry number " + (input + 1)). I want to computer to ask Please enter entry number 1.... to what the user input. If the user enters 5, your code would print Please enter entry number 6. That would be inaccurate because the first number 1 not six.

Comment: @JimRoberts: Sorry, that was a typo - fixed now. But that's pretty much irrelevant to the actual problem.

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the extra zero, by removing the equal sign from my last for loop. Still don't understand where it came from though. @John Skeet

Comment: @Jim: That suggests you haven't understood my answer. Your array is bigger than it should be.